# Python mapraduce in spark

Tags: javascript, python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have some text, and i must calc count of some words (e.g John and marry) with hadoop.

In java script i can write this like this:

```
require('timothy').map(function(line){
        emit("count", 1);
        if(new RegExp("john", "i").test(line))     emit("John", 1);
        if(new RegExp("marry", "i").test(line))    emit("Marry", 1);
    }).reduce(function(key, values){
        var result = 0;
        values.forEach(function(value){
            result += +value;
        });

        emit(key, result);
}).run();
```

I use map function for all lines and write data for each match. Now i want do this with Spark, but i must write in python. I have some code:

```
import sys
import re

from operator import add
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: wordcount <file>"
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
    lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1], 1)

    def map(line):
        #here must contains map function;


    counts = lines.map(map).reduceByKey(add)
    output = counts.collect()
    for (word, count) in output:
        print "%s: %i" % (word, count)

    sc.stop()
```

My problem is that I can only record one match returned (key, val), How to make similarly to the first example. Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

If you question is how can I emit multiple values in the map phase. The answer is use the `flatMap` operator with a function that returns a sequence of values instead of a single value. The sequence will be split by the flatMap transformation. For instance:

```
file = spark.textFile("file://...")
counts = file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
         .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

The `line.split(" ")` returns a sequence of strings.